# PHP mysqldump issues

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to write a PHP mysqldump script to be run from a webpage, and I am having issues with it; **the script seemingly runs, but when I go to the directory I specified for it to dump the database to, there is nothing.**

This is the php file for the mysqldump script:

```
?php
require( "config.php" );
exec(' mysqldump -u [$DB_USERNAME] -p [$DB_PASSWORD] [$DB_NAME] > bzpbackup.sql');
echo ' <html> Database backup complete! Please click the link below to 
download backup. 
<br> 
<form target="http://solismagna.com/dbbackups/bzpbackup.sql type="submit">
Download Backup</form> </html> ';
?>
```

This file is called sqldump.php. The config.php file stores the variables I use for the mysqldump username, password, and database name. Previously, I had the directory to dump to set to **"home/dbbackups/bzpbackup.sql"**, but I removed that, thinking it may have been an incorrect directory. Also, as you can see, I am trying to output a message to index.php upon the script's completion. This: **"bzpbackup.sql'); echo ' Database backup complete! Please click the link below to download backup. 
Download Backup"** shows up regardless of whether or not the script has been completed yet. I used the following code to output that on the index.php page:

```
?php $f="sqldump.php";
$data = file_get_contents($f);
echo $data;
?>
```

Here is the config.php file:

```
<?php
ini_set( "display_errors", true );
date_default_timezone_set( "America/New_York" );

define( "DB_USERNAME", "username" );
define( "DB_PASSWORD", "password" );
define( "DB_NAME", "database" );

require( "sqldump.php" );

/*function handleException( $exception ) {
echo "Sorry, a problem occurred. Please try later.";
error_log( $exception->getMessage() );
}

set_exception_handler( 'handleException' );*/
?>
```

Could the problem be that I required sqldump.php in the config file?

Anyway, I cannot tell whether or not the script is truly working or not when I click the "Start Database Backup" button on the index.php file.

Speaking of which here is the code for that button:

```
<form action="sqldump.php" type="submit" method="get">
<button type="submit">Start Database Backup</button>
</form>
```

What is the default directory for mysqldumps, and are my backups currently being stored there? Also, should I include config.php in the head of index.php? I also want the download button to appear upon completion of the script. Could someone please tell me how to do this?

Sorry for such a long question. I'm still very much so a novice at PHP.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the "home/dbbackups/bzpbackup.sql" location again, but put a forward slash at the beginning. So, "/home/dbbackups/bzpbackup.sql".

Also, ensure that the "/home/dbbackups" directory is writable by any user by using:

```
chmod ugo+w /home/dbbackups
```

Comment: Just tried that, and I got this error. I even CHMODed dbbackups to 777, but I got this error: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@solismagna.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: http://php.net/phpinfo will show you where the log file is located. If you read the end of that log (or tail it), you can see which error is being triggered. Also, please ensure that http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php is turned on.

Comment: Turned on error reporting for that file, and I unexpectedly got an entire page of these errors, but nothing else: Notice: Constant DB_USERNAME already defined in /home/sphefsfa/public_html/cmstest/config.php on line 6

Notice: Constant DB_PASSWORD already defined in /home/sphefsfa/public_html/cmstest/config.php on line 7

Notice: Constant DB_HOST already defined in /home/sphefsfa/public_html/cmstest/config.php on line 8

Notice: Constant DB_NAME already defined in /home/sphefsfa/public_html/cmstest/config.php on line 9